# Code can't find keys in dictionary when prompted with string sequence

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop, key

Newbie at coding, doing this for university. I have written a dictionary which translates codons into single letter amino acids. However, my function can't find the keys in the dict and just adds an X to the list I've made. See code below:

```
codon_table = {('TTT', 'TTC'): 'F',
               ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'): 'L',
               ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'): 'I',
               ('ATG'): 'M',
               ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'): 'V',
               ('TCT', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCG'): 'S',
               ('CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'): 'P',
               ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'): 'T',
               ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'): 'A',
               ('TAT', 'TAC'): 'Y',
               ('CAT', 'CAC'): 'H',
               ('CAA', 'CAG'): 'Q',
               ('AAT', 'AAC'): 'N',
               ('AAA', 'AAG'): 'K',
               ('GAT', 'GAC'): 'D',
               ('GAA', 'GAG'): 'E',
               ('TGT', 'TGC'): 'C',
               ('TGG'): 'W',
               ('CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'): 'R',
               ('AGT', 'AGC'): 'S',
               ('GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'): 'G',
               ('TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA'): '*',
               }
AA_seq = []

input_DNA = str(input('Please input a DNA string: '))

def translate_dna():
    list(input_DNA)
    global AA_seq
    for codon in range(0, len(input_DNA), 3):
        if codon in codon_table:
            AA_seq = codon_table[codon]
            AA_seq.append(codon_table[codon])
        else:
            AA_seq.append('X')
    print(str(' '.join(AA_seq)).strip('[]').replace("'", ""))

translate_dna()
```

Inputted a DNA sequence, eg TGCATGCTACGTAGCGGACCTGG, which would only return XXXXXXX. What I would expect is a string of single letters corresponding to the amino acids in the dict.

I've been staring at it for the best part of an hour, so I figured it's time to ask the experts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *codon in codon_table* will never return True because *codon* is an integer whereas all your dictionary keys are tuples

Answer (score 1):

You need a codon dictionary keyed on single codons.

Then you need to iterate over the input sequence in groups of 3.

You also need to decide what the output should look like if a triplet is not found in your lookup dictionary.

For example:

```
from functools import cache

codon_table = {('TTT', 'TTC'): 'F',
               ('TTA', 'TTG', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTG'): 'L',
               ('ATT', 'ATC', 'ATA'): 'I',
               ('ATG'): 'M',
               ('GTT', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTG'): 'V',
               ('TCT', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCG'): 'S',
               ('CCT', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCG'): 'P',
               ('ACT', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACG'): 'T',
               ('GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'): 'A',
               ('TAT', 'TAC'): 'Y',
               ('CAT', 'CAC'): 'H',
               ('CAA', 'CAG'): 'Q',
               ('AAT', 'AAC'): 'N',
               ('AAA', 'AAG'): 'K',
               ('GAT', 'GAC'): 'D',
               ('GAA', 'GAG'): 'E',
               ('TGT', 'TGC'): 'C',
               ('TGG'): 'W',
               ('CGT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGG', 'AGA', 'AGG'): 'R',
               ('AGT', 'AGC'): 'S',
               ('GGT', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGG'): 'G',
               ('TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA'): '*',
               }

@cache
def lookup(codon):
    for k, v in codon_table.items():
        if codon in k:
            return v
    return '?'


sequence = 'TGCATGCTACGTAGCGGACCTGG'

AA_Seq = []

for i in range(0, len(sequence), 3):
    AA_Seq.append(lookup(sequence[i:i+3]))

print(AA_Seq)
```

**Output:**

```
['C', 'M', 'L', 'R', 'S', 'G', 'P', '?']
```

**Note:**

The ? appears because the last item extracted from the input sequence is 'GG' which is not a valid codon.

Also note that the key/value pair in codon_table of ('ATG'): 'M' is not a tuple/string pair. ('ATG') is just a string (the parentheses are irrelevant). You could write it as ('ATG',): 'M' to make the key a 1-tuple

Comment: Thanks but your code is way too complex for me, is there no way to change what I've written so that it works?

Comment: @assignmentdeath207 Edited to use a slightly simpler but less efficient approach

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop goes through input and inside it can't find any matches and appends "X" to your `AA_seq`

This is because

- you are trying to access only 1 element in the input string rather than 3
- your dictionary keys are tuples, which means `"TTT"` is not the same
  thing as `("TTT",)`

To fix this:

- You have to reorder your dictionary to only use single value for key instead of a tuple.
- You have to loop through your input such as `[i:i+3]` to get a string length of three

Comment: How would I change the tuples to single keys? I'm not really sure what a tuple is tbh

Comment: tuple is a datatype that holds many different values in it. Here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) to website that explains what tuples are.